# I lost my gmap macro builder

Tags: 7, google-maps

I'm embarrassed but I can't find the gmap macro builder anymore. I looked under

`config->content-authoring->location` and all its tabs
as well as `configuration->web services-> GMap` and all its tabs
and `configuration->web services->GMap location` and everything under that.

I also made sure that GMAp macro builder module is enabled

The following modules are also enabled:

- Gmap 7.x-1.x dev
- Gmap location 7.x-1.x dev
- Gmap macro builder 7.x-1.x dev
- Gmap taxonomy markers 7.x-1.x dev
- Location 7.x - 4x dev
- Location add another  7.x - 4x dev
- Location Search 7.x -4.x ev
- Node locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A peek in [the code](http://drupalcode.org/project/gmap.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/gmap_macro_builder.module) reveals that the macro builder registers the path map/macro.

```
function gmap_macro_builder_menu() {
  $items['map/macro'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'title' => 'Build a GMap macro',
    'access arguments' => array('create gmap macro'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('gmap_macro_builder_form'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

It is understandably hard to find when it's not under admin; though, perhaps, gmap registers map for its own set of admin pages.

Comment: @kiamlaluno The references to Drupal paths is now inconsistent, with one path within ``, and two without. Is that intentional?

Comment: Whoops… No, it's not intentional.

Comment: That is awfully correct. Helped me out fantastic.